# Action Script 3. How to control elements from 2nd level array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript, element

So I have stupid question. If I have added A array to other B array, how can I control A array's elements?

I mean If I have Array A (**length 4**):

```
Jennifer Jessica John Peter
```

To Array B I have pushed some data `(arrB.push(item1); (arrB.push(item1);...`, so It looks like (**length 6**):

```
test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6
```

After It, I have pushed Array B to Array A `arrA.push(arrB);` Now Array's A **length is 5** and It looks like:

```
Jennifer Jessica John Peter (test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6)
```

All this data `test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6` from array B is like 5th element of Array A.

If I use `trace(arrA[4]);` It returns me `test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6` But for example how can I get test2? I've tried `trace(arrA[4].arrB[1]);`, but It returns me undefinied.

Is It possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a traditional multi-dimensional array. For example `arrA[2][1]` in my example below will give you `o` the second letter of `John` not an index into a second array.

Instead you have an array that has multiple elements, one of which is an array object. To access `test2` you would use `arrA[4][1]`. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpAck/1/)**.

```
var arrA = ['Jennifer','Jessica','John','Peter'];
var arrB = ['test1','test2','test3','test4'];
arrA.push(arrB);
arrA.push('fred');
console.log(arrA);
console.log(arrA[4][1]);
console.log(arrA[5]);
console.log(arrA[2][1]);
```

The output will be the array then `test2` then `fred`, then `o`.

This makes a it a bit tricky when you traverse the array in a generic manner, you will need to check whether you are dealing with a string or a string array. Was you intention a multi-dim array or a collection of objects some which are strings and some which are string arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You'd access it like this:

```
trace(arrA[4][1]);
```